# iOS Cordova app auto zoom on input after migrating to 6.1.1

Tags: javascript, ios, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

After migrating to Cordova ios version from **5.1.0** to **6.1.1** facing zoom issue on the focus of input. Tried a couple of solutions but both of them are causing new issues

- Adding `font-size: 16px !important`: issues with this solution is it increases the size input too much.
- Adding `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">`, issues with this solution is it disable the keyboard behaviour of moving content on top of keyboard and even no scrolling happen when keyboard appears.

[Root screen page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/107fF.png)